# how to read users gmail using google admin sdk and gmail api

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, google-workspace, service-accounts, google-api-nodejs-client

I am new to google admin SDK and workspace.
First, I would like to apologize for my broken English and grammar.
I'm trying to read emails of my all workspace users using admin SDK and Gmail API with node js.
I have already set up the domain-wide delegation and added my google service app to my admin console. (my service app account is different from the workspace account and also the app is not published).Please help me out with it :) Thanks
scopes, error, code is given below
scopes i have used for oauth:

```
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',<br>
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',<br>
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly',<br>
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',<br>
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.domain',<br>
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing',<br>
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.security']<br>
```

Note: i am login with my superadmin account(email@domain.com)

> Error:`The API returned an error:s Error: Delegation denied for email@domain.com`
> note: email@domain.com is super admin email id

code:

```
app.get('/link',function(req,res){
  if (!req.cookies.authed) {
      // Generate an OAuth URL and redirect there
      const url = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.domain','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.security']
      });
      res.render('pages/link',{gulr:url})
    } else {
      const oA2Ct = new google.auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL);
      const auth = oA2Ct.setCredentials(req.cookies._aGT);

      admin_sdk_read_gmail (auth);//login with email@domain.com(super admin auth)
    }
});
app.get('/link/auth/google/callback', function (req, res) {
    const code = req.query.code
    if (code) {
        // Get an access token based on our OAuth code
        oAuth2Client.getToken(code, function (err, tokens) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            
            logger.debug('Successfully authenticated');
            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
            res.cookie('authed', true, { maxAge:99999999, httpOnly: true });
            res.cookie('_aGT', tokens, { maxAge:99999999, httpOnly: true });
            res.redirect('/link')
        });
    }
});
function admin_sdk_read_gmail (auth) {//auth is var from oauth
  const service = google.admin({version: 'directory_v1', auth});
  service.users.list({
    customer: 'my_customer',
    maxResults: 10,
    orderBy: 'email',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.error('The API returned an error:', err.message);
    const users = res.data.users;
    console.log('Users:');
    console.log(users[0].primaryEmail);//admin
    console.log(users[1].primaryEmail);//user
    const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: auth });
    gmail.users.messages.list({
      userId:users[1].primaryEmail, 
      maxResults:500,
      q:`in:anywhere  after:2022/07/01 before:2022/07/08`
      }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error:s ' + err);
        console.log(res)
    });
  });
  }
```

Comment: please edit your question and show us the code you are using for authorization.  How are you getting auth

Comment: Is the `auth` parameter where the email impersonation is being made? If so, could you share the code that you are currently using?

Comment: @DaImTo sorry for the inconvenience I updated my code. thanks

Comment: I think you should consult https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation  you have not properly configured delegation to that user.

Comment: @DaImTo I just checked everything is done according to this guide https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

Comment: The API returned an error:s Error: Delegation denied for email@domain.com  <--- says its not.

Comment: The thing is i am a little confused that doesnt look like service account authentication code.   It looks like web Oauth2 code.

Comment: @DaImTo yes i am using web Oauth2

Comment: Well there's your problem.  You can only use a service account.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused. You are trying to connect workspace to gmail api using domain wide delegation.  Which is correct.

However this only works with service account authentication.  you appear to be using web oauth2 code.

I think that you should consult this page [Service account](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#service-account-credentials)

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: '/path/to/your-secret-key.json',
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail'],
});

const getGmailApi = async () => {
  const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
    scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail"],
  });
  // delegate to user on domain.
  auth.subject = process.env.GOOGLE_ADMIN_EMAIL;
  return gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
};
```

Make sure to create a [service account](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asrCdWFrF0A) key file and enable gmail under library

Comment: I tried the above code and checked both the video and GitHub examples. and having the following error: ``` GoogleAuth {
  checkIsGCE: undefined,
  jsonContent: null,
  cachedCredential: null,
  _cachedProjectId: null,
  keyFilename: './secret-key.json',
  scopes: [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail' ],
  clientOptions: undefined
}```

Comment: are you sure you are using a service account token  open your keyfile and check that it says its a service account.

Comment: Thanks for helping me and also for clearing most of the concept...problem is fixed I switch and tried JWT and it's working fine. your above code is having some problems with the secret-key.json file. i implemented that logic with JWT and its working once again thanks

Comment: @imtiyaz Can you perhaps edit your question to include how you made this work with JWT? Facing a similar issue.

Comment: sure sorry i will just update it